# Why does OnLaunched check if (rootFrame.Content == null)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

In the `OnLaunched` method that's in the `App` class, there is the following:

```
if (rootFrame.Content == null)
{
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
}
```

Why does it check if the `Content` is `null`? Obviously it ***will*** be, since the `OnLaunched` method is

> "Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user. 
>   Other entry points will be used such as when the application is
>   launched to open a specific file." (from its summary.)

The reason given in the comment to the null check is:

> "When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first
>   page,..."

But it will never be "restored" as above. This would make sense in a `Resuming` event handler, not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnLaunched` will be invoked any time the user opens an app through the Start menu, a tile, or any other action that normally launches an app, even if the app is already running or was previously suspended rather than terminated.

Note that in the WinRT 8.1 templates, state is restored in the `if (rootFrame == null)` check that appears before this check, *within* the `OnLaunched` handler.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds right. I didn't think of that. (Can't accept yet.)